# How to add a hyperlink in Hotmail (live.com)?

Tags: outlook.com, links

I have an email address ending with @outlook.com. I am replying to an e-mail right now and I can't find any button to add a link (or hyperlink).

I have the buttons to add an image, to format the text in bold, italic, etc, but I can't find any option to add a link.

This is the toolbar that I have:

[image: Live.com buttons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button to insert an hyperlink is in the dropdown menu. Just Click on the V button:

[image: Outlook message editor toolbar]

Comment: Keep in mind, this option only is available if you choose to open the "Open in a separate window" option